# Setting the default value of a function input to equal another input in Python

Tags: python, function, default-value, keyword-argument

Consider the following function, which does not work in Python, but I will use to explain what I need to do.

```py
def exampleFunction(a, b, c = a):
    ...function body...
```

That is I want to assign to variable `c` the same value that variable `a` would take, unless an alternative value is specified. The above code does not work in python. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
def example(a, b, c=None):
    if c is None:
        c = a
    ...
```

The default value for the keyword argument can't be a variable (if it is, it's converted to a fixed value when the function is defined.)  Commonly used to pass arguments to a main function:

```
def main(argv=None):
    if argv is None:
        argv = sys.argv
```

If `None` could be a valid value, the solution is to either use `*args`/`**kwargs` magic as in carl's answer, or use a *sentinel object*. Libraries that do this include [attrs](https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs/blob/dc1b5a01e/src/attr/_make.py#L67-L74) and [Marshmallow](https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow/blob/c4d98d9df/src/marshmallow/fields.py#L264), and in my opinion it's much cleaner and likely faster.

```
missing = object()

def example(a, b, c=missing):
    if c is missing:
        c = a
    ...
```

The *only* way for `c is missing` to be true is for `c` to be *exactly* that dummy object you created there.

Comment: Exactly. Default arguments are set in stone once the function is defined.

Comment: @delnan Is this the reason why can not supply the non-default set argument at the last like `def(x=2,y)` rather I have to define function as `def(y, x=2)`?

Answer (score 17):

This general pattern is probably the best and most readable:

```
def exampleFunction(a, b, c = None):
    if c is None:
        c = a
    ...
```

You have to be careful that `None` is not a valid state for `c`.

If you want to support 'None' values, you can do something like this:

```
def example(a, b, *args, **kwargs):
    if 'c' in kwargs:
        c = kwargs['c']
    elif len(args) > 0:
        c = args[0]
    else:
        c = a
```

Comment: +1 for being mentioning that `None` can't be a valid state for `c` for the `c=None` trick to work.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is something like:

```
def foo(a, b, c=None):
    c = a if c is None else c
    # do something
```